# $(a,b) = 1$ iff whenever $p$ is prime and $p \vert a$, then $p \nmid b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

here is my proof attempt:

$\Rightarrow$ Direction;

Since $(a,b) = 1$, $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ $\ni$

$ax + by = 1$

But $p \vert a$ $\Rightarrow$ $p \vert ax$

Suppose towards a contradiction that $p \vert b$, then $p \vert by$, hence

$p \vert ax + by$

$p \vert 1$

Contradiction since $p$ is prime, $\therefore$ $p \nmid b$.

$\Leftarrow$ Direction;

Let $a = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdot \cdot \cdot p_m^{e_m}$ and $b = q_1^{f_1}q_2^{f_2} \cdot \cdot \cdot q_n^{f_n}$ ; not all $e_i,f_i$ zero.

We want to show

$p_i^{e_i} \neq q_j^{e_j}$ (**) for no $i,j$ between 1 and $m,n$ resp.

But $p \vert a$ $\Rightarrow$ $p = p_i^{e_i}$ some $i, 1 \leq i \leq m$

By our assumption, $p \vert a$ $\Rightarrow$ $p \nmid b$

$\Rightarrow$ $p = p_i^{e_i} \neq q_j^{f_j}$ for any $j$.

Hence (**) satisfied, ($a$, $b$ share no common prime factors), $\Rightarrow$ $(a,b) = 1$

I use the FTOA when rewriting $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Looks ok, but you don't need the FTOA: Suppose $(a,b)\ne 1$. Then there exists $p$ with $p\mid (a,b)$, hence $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$

Comment: $(\Rightarrow)$ is correct, but you should invoke Bezout *by name* to justify the claim. Otoh, while you seem to have the correct idea of a FTOA-based proof in $(\Leftarrow)$, the presentation has various problems, e.g. $p = p^e_i$  should be $p = p_i$  in a couple paces, you need to justify why no common prime factor implies gcd $= 1$, you missed the case $a,b = 1,1$ by assuming not all $e_i,f_j$ zero, etc.

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks ya I know I have to state that for the forward direction. and In the proof I am turning in I state not all the powers are zero. other than those I shoaled be ok?

Comment: yeah the step of why no common prime factor implies gcd = 1, I am having trouble rigorously stating this or justifying, thank you both so much!!!!

Comment: What you've done looks fine to me. However, for the first part, I believe it would be a bit simpler to say that given $(a,b)=1$ that with $p \mid a$, use contradiction that if $p \mid b$ then, by definition of gcd that $p \mid (a,b)$, which is not true as $(a,b)=1$, so this shows that $p \nmid b$.

Comment: @John Au contraire, there are many issues with $(\Leftarrow)$ (see my prior comment). Please be more careful.

Comment: @BillDubuque It seems I didn't read the question carefully enough. Thanks for pointing this out.